# Gnome classic + Unity Dash

Tags: unity, gnome, gnome-classic

I like GNOME Classic more then GNOME Shell or Unity because it has a taskbar and Applications and Places menus on top. But the one thing i am really really missing is the dash from GNOME 3 and Unity, that comes up when I press the "Super" key.

How can I use GNOME Shell  with the task bar and the Applications and Places on top, *or* use GNOME Classic with the Unity dash, *or* use GNOME Classic with an alternative launcher?

Comment: I use `gnome-session-fallback` for the desktop and `gnome-do` to search for apps, it's just like `launchy` for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use unity or gnome and get the functionality you like about Gnome Classic. There is a Classic Menu Indicator, for instance.

Here is a quote from http://maketecheasier.com/10-must-have-indicator-applets-for-ubuntu-12-04/2012/06/15:

> ClassicMenu Indicator:
>
> Aw! You miss the good old classic Gnome2 menu which stayed with Ubuntu
>   till version 10.10 but bid farewell since Ubuntu switched to
>   Unity/Gnome 3. Here is a good news fellas! We have this tiny little
>   applet that gives you (to an extent) same classic menu feel.
>
> [image]
>
> The .deb file is available to be downloaded from here.
>   - See more at: http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Environment/Tools/ClassicMenu-Indicator-70007.shtml

That indicator is written by Florian Diesch (also a Ask Ubuntu user).

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 12.04, there is a way to get the Dash. However, this includes also enabling launcher.

Start `unity-2d-shell` as described here: [Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome Classic and Unity Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/q/261897/55343)

You will get the unity launcher, from which you can open the dash. Or use the `super/windows` key.

For autohiding the launcher in 12.04 see this question: [Autohide Unity Launcher in Gnome Classic](https://askubuntu.com/q/262585/55343).