# Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome Classic and Unity Launcher

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome-classic

Is there any possibility to get the new unity launcher while having the Gnome classic desktop?

I enabled the classic desktop as described: [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic-desktop/108916#108916)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By issuing the command `unity-2d-shell`, you will launch the launcher.

Here is what you have to do, to automatically do this on startup:

1. Open `Startup Applications`

   [image: Open <code>Startup Applications</code>]
2. `Add Startup Program`
   [image: Add Startup Program]
3. For autohiding the launcher in 12.04 see this question: [Autohide Unity Launcher in Gnome Classic](https://askubuntu.com/q/262585/55343).