# Autohide Unity Launcher in Gnome Classic

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome-classic

I am using the Unity launcher in the Gnome Classic desktop. How can I enable the autohide feature for the launcher?

---

**Background information:**

I reverted to Gnome Classic Desktop as described here: [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic-desktop/108916#108916)

Next, I start `unity-2d-shell` as described here: [Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome Classic and Unity Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/q/261897/55343)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `dconf-editor` (`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`).

There, go to com => canonical => unity-2d => launcher:

Set `hide-mode` to 1. Instantly, the launcher will hide!

More detailed information can be found here: [How do I configure Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32667/how-do-i-configure-unity-2d), especially this answer for 12.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/105682/55343